# html button disappears after onclick() event

Tags: javascript, html, web

Hello guys I am New to javascript I want to know why does the html button disappears as soon as i click it. The browser shows the text but the button disappears.  here is how my html looks likes

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function funcname(){
                document.write("<br/>  <br/> <br/> some text");
            }
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" name="something" value="touch me" onclick="funcname()"> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thats what document.write does. It after an HTML document is fully loaded, will delete all existing HTML.

Comment: If you want to add content you should use document.writeIn()

Comment: Ow right, dont look at what i said >.>

Answer (score 2):

The write() method writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document.

The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

Answer from: [source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

Comment: `The write() method is mostly used for testing` in the 90's

Answer (score 2):

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   function funcname()
   {

       document.body.innerHTML += "Some Text";
   }

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>

   <form>
   <input type="button" name="something" value="touch me" onclick="funcname()"> 
   </form>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Try above code it will work fine.If you use document.write() overwritten body so should be use document.body.innerHTML .

Answer (score 1):

The Document.write function overwrites the document content when called, as stated by the Mozilla Developer Network:

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open which will clear the document.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` will override your whole `body` element. If you want to override only specific parts, you could define a target and use `innerHTML` to change the text.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function funcname(){
                document.getElementById("someParagraph").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" name="something" value="touch me" onclick="funcname()"> 
        </form>
        <p id="someParagraph">Hey<p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jep, confused the words "scope" and "target", thanks :)